# The logarithm of a product

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, products

Let $p$ be a prime number, $C\in \mathbb{N}$ and C is not a square. Then define
$$F=\prod_{|z| \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} \atop |y|\leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2D}}}{|z^2-Cy^2|}.$$ Note that we omit the term with $z=0=y$. (So the product is not zero.) Now my question: Why does the following inequality hold for $x>x_0$ (i.e. the inequality holds if x is "large enough")?

$$\log(F)>\frac{x}{\sqrt{C}}\log(x)$$

Edit: Something in Selbergs paper was not clear and I think there was also a little mistake. In the product above we have $|y|\leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2D}}$ and not $|y|\leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}p}$. I changed that.

Comment: There is no $x_0$ in the definition, but there is in the claim. What's up with that?

Comment: This $x_0$ says that the inequality has to hold if x is "big enough".

Comment: Is the product over $\Bbb Z^2$ (without $0$, under those bounds)? Also, if $C$ is a square this will be zero for $x$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I'm sorry. The product is over $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but C is not a square. I will edit the question.

Comment: If you're asking why it holds, then you are asserting that it holds. What is your evidence for it holding?

Comment: It's just a little step in this proof [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969454?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103928493137). You can find it on p.301 in the proof of Lemma 1. (I changed the notation a little bit).